# Class method don't update attribute

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.success = True
    def method(self):
        self.success = False

test = Test("tree")
test.method
print(test.success)   

#output is: True
```

I need to check if the operation programmed in "method" is successful. So, on success, I update the "success" attribute declared in the constructor. But when I call the method after creating the class object, the attribute is not updated.

Comment: `test.method` should be `test.method()`

Comment: call the method...`test.method()`

Comment: Why is this? The class has no method attribute, it should send an error I think.

Comment: @Carlitos_30 in Python, class's method name is an attribute, you can assign it some variable like `function = test.method` or assigned to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke a method,you have to use parenthesis. In short,

> test.method() is the correct way to call the method.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling your method() correctly.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.success = True
    def method(self):
        self.success = False

test = Test("tree")
test.method()  # NOTE the parentheses here
print(test.success)
```